# std::packaged_task<T>'s allocator constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading

The std::packaged_task template has one constructor that accepts an allocator:

```
packaged_task pt {allocator_arg_t, a, f};
```

I'd like to ask:

1) It's presence indicates that a packaged_task object might need memory to store data. Such a requirement is obvious in case of a container (eg: a vector). However, a packaged_task isn't a container.

If 'f' (the task passed as argument to the packaged_task) needs space, the responsibility for providing that space is that of 'f' and not of the packaged_task (else 'f' wouldn't run outside of a packaged_task).

Therefore, why is this constructor needed for a packaged_task?

2) What is the allocator_arg_t argument, why is it needed and how is it used?

3) Is there a (simple) usage example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allocator-aware overload has been removed since C++17.

`packaged_task` stores a copy of `f`, which is initialized with `std::forward<F>(f)`. The storage is allocated using allocator `a`. This copy is necessary, because the `packaged_task` may out-live the original `f`.

[`std::allocator_arg_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_arg_t) is purely used to disambiguate the overloads of constructors. To select the allocator-aware constructor, you pass [`std::allocator_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_arg) as the first argument.

An example ([live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xIKZQIjpM0qP1Tjs)):

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int one() noexcept {
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  std::packaged_task<int()> task(std::allocator_arg, std::allocator<void>{}, one);
  task();
  std::cout << task.get_future().get() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `1`.